# Is it possible to get `mvn tomcat6:run` to work correctly with a filtered web.xml?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a project that needs to have `${}` placeholder substitution applied to `web.xml` that I want to run for development mode with `mvn tomcat6:run`. Is it possible to set this up?

---

This is a legacy codebase where I'm trying to introduce both deployment environments to get rid of the previous process that was "copy web.xml variants around and edit a config file and keep this out of source control." I also want to avoid having to maintain a Tomcat installation and setting up an IDE to deploy to it, and just have the application execute using `tomcat6-maven-plugin`.

What I have so far is this project layout:

```
foo
│   pom.xml
│
└───src
    └───main
        ├───environments
        │   ├───BAR
        │   │       filter.properties
        │   │
        │   └───FOO
        │           filter.properties
        │
        ├───java
        │   └───se
        │       └───millimoo
        │               IndexServlet.java
        │
        └───webapp
            └───WEB-INF
                    web.xml
```

#### `pom.xml`

```
...
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/environments/${environment}/filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/environments/${environment}</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>env-foo</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <environment>FOO</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>env-bar</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>BAR</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

That is: I add the directory for an environment as a resource; tell Maven to load placeholder values from `filter.properties` in that directory; and tell the WAR plugin to filter the deployment descriptors. I also set up two profiles to switch between the environments.

#### `FOO\filter.properties`

```
filter.environment=foofoo
```

#### `BAR\filter.properties`

```
filter.environment=barbar
```

#### `web.xml`

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>se.millimoo.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>environment</param-name>
        <param-value>${filter.environment}</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

#### `IndexServlet.java`

Prints the value of the `environment` init param.

---

What happens is that when I run this using `mvn tomcat6:run`, it uses the unfiltered `web.xml`, which is obviously not what I want. The filtered version is used when I use `mvn tomcat6:run-war`, but I'm not a fan of that: it's slower, and has other issues in my real code that generally slow down turnaround, which is the point of the exercise. (It uses the JAR files of dependent projects where the backend code is from the Maven repository to build the JAR, which can be either outdated or not available at all if I haven't installed them after a version number bump; rather than using the current code.)

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds here? Be able to run the app server through maven or in another easily embedded way, while also having filtering applied to web.xml? Preferrably without significantly changing the app itself, i.e. I don't want to load the configuration values without using servlet init params. (In the real code, the servlet is a third-party one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the goal I want is `tomcat6:run-war-only`, which starts a Tomcat over the assembled webapp in `target/`. However, this goal doesn't invoke the rest of the lifecycle when run on its own, meaning the app might not be assembled or up-to-date. I resolved this by first replacing the `war:war` goal with `war:war-exploded` in the `package` phase of the lifecycle, and binding `tomcat6:run-war-only` to `verify`, the next lifecycle phase. (Which, conveniently enough, doesn't have any goals bound for `war` projects, and seems appropriate semantically.) To keep this contained, I put it into a profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>embedded</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replace running war:war with war:exploded in the lifecycle -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>embedded-war</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run Tomcat over the assembled webapp -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>embedded-verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-war-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Combined with what's already given in the question, to run the `foo` environment, you use:

```
mvn -P embedded,env-foo verify
```

One flaw this has is that it won't reflect live changes to views or such, but running `mvn war:exploded` to reassemble the app while the Tomcat server is running should take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add this in your `pom.xml` so Maven knows he needs to filter this directory too :

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
</build>
```

### EDIT

**As discused in the commentaries, this approach might not be a good solution.**

Another solution :

- From  [Apache Maven WAR Plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

> **Overriding the default destination directory**
>
> By default web resources are copied to the root of the WAR, as shown
>   in the previous example. To override the default destination
>   directory, specify the target path.
>
> ```
>         ...
>         <configuration>
>           <webResources>
>             <resource>
>               ...
>             </resource>
>             <resource>
>               <directory>configurations</directory>
>               <!-- override the destination directory for this resource -->
>               <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
>               <!-- enable filtering -->
>               <filtering>true</filtering>
>               <excludes>
>                 <exclude>**/properties</exclude>
>               </excludes>
>             </resource>
>           </webResources>
>         </configuration>
>         ...
> ```

In this example, we override a directory but maybe it's possible to override a single file.

Comment: That includes the contents of that directory in the final build’s `WEB-INF/classes`, meaning that the WAR will have two copies of that directory’s contents nested in one another - one with filtered files, one without. This sounds like a fantastic way to get very confusing bugs, bloats the WAR and makes its build even slower, and also might not work, since the Tomcat plugin might still load web.xml from the source directory. (I’ll check that last part later.)

Comment: But generally, there’s a reason why the WAR plugin handles that directory on its own, and it’s not included under `<resources>`

Comment: I understand. As you said, it might not be a good solution. I will edit my answer.

Comment: But I don't want to copy anything under WEB-INF from another resource directory, `web.xml` already is in the default location `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF`. I tried creating a new directory `src/main/WEB.INF.filtered` that contains my `web.xml` with `<targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>`. The WAR builds correctly - but it did that before. However, `tomcat6:run` doesn't find my IndexServlet; which makes sense, because there no longer is a `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`. The main issue seems to be that the Tomcat plugin just ignores any configuration in the `WAR` plugin regarding web resources.